# WinSCP connection refused

Tags: ubuntu

I have newer worked with networking and SSH but I have a task with it.
On virtual machine I have a Ubuntu on real machine I have a Windows; I need to write a programm in Windows, which is create a user in Ubuntu. How I suggested, I need to write a script to create a user on remote machine using ssh.I download a WinSCP and try to connect with my virtual machine typing in Host name Ubuntu IP, and have a error connection refused. What I did wrong?

Comment: Why you use WinSCP as it's for transfering files, not executing commands and why you just not ssh to the machin and execute adduser command?

Comment: I don't know nothing about it, I use WinSCP because it is a ssh client.

Comment: Now when I run SSH on Ubuntu, I have a Connection timed out on PuTTy and WinSCP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you, or someone else created a user on this server for you?

I havent used winSCP recently, does it have remote shell capabilities? I understood it to be a scp client (ssh secure copy). You may want to get yourself [Putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html)

But make sure that your user has been created properly first.

I assume you can access the server from a the vm console.
Is sshd running? `ps -ef | grep sshd`

Try sshing locally on the ubuntu server (again assuming you are able to access), and paste the output of `ssh -v localhost`

If you arent able to access the ubuntu server from the vm console and you cant ssh in, and you were the one that installs it, theres not a lot I can suggest.

Comment: I try to use Putty, but It is the same error in it. I create a user in Ubuntu when I install it.

Comment: So you are the administrator, and installer for this VM? Is ssh enabled, is the network up, are you trying to access it from another network, is the network accessable, are there firewalls in between. Can you 'ping' this server from where you are? Is there anything else running on this server that you can access? for example http on port 80?

Comment: Yes I'm administrator and installer this VM, ssh not enabled on VM, I'm trying to access from my real machin in virtual machine, the network is  accessable (I think so, bechose when I run console on windows i see  network which call VirtualBox Host-Only and it's IP and in ubuntu when I run Terminal and typing ifconfig I see the IP of this network)

Comment: Install sshd `sudo apt-get install openssh-server openssh-client`

Comment: //sudo apt-get install openssh-server openssh-client- this comannd isn't work its talk "cannot stat 'openssh-server' no such file in directory"

Answer (score 1):

- Is a SSH server installed and configured on the VM?
- Did you enter any security credentials (username/password, SSH key)? In general, you'll need some kind of authentication to connect via SSH

Comment: I don't installed and configured ssh server on VM, how i can do it?